# How can I determine if a user has subscribed to a specific channel when using Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I used the Python library and I want users to check if they have subscribed to the specified channel when using the robot.

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient('Bot', api_id, api_hash)

async def is_participant(channel, user) -> bool:
    offset_user = 0
    limit = 100

    channel_entity = await client.get_entity(channel)
    while True:
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(
            channel_entity,
            ChannelParticipantsSearch(user),
            offset=offset_user,
            limit=limit,
            hash=0
        ))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        if participants:
            return True
    return False
```

The above is my code, which traverses the users of the channel and compares it with the current user using the robot. If the username is the same, it returns True, otherwise it returns False.

But there is a problem with doing this because some Telegram accounts do not have a username. Moreover, traversing is a waste of time.

The effect I want is to identify a user through the permanent ID of the Telegram account and make judgments based on the permanent ID of the channel user. How should I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In V1:

```py
from telethon import errors, TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient('Bot', api_id, api_hash)

async def is_participant(channel, user) -> bool:
    try:
        await client.get_permissions(channel, user)
        return True
    except errors.UserNotParticipantError:
        return False
```

Comment: thanks bro, it work. but so slowly

Comment: You're probably not expected to do this. You can instead poll the admin log (`get_admin_log`) every 24h to get all new joins, and won't miss any.